# Is there a way to approximate the terms of $\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}$ for successive $n$ as $n$ becomes large?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, products, upper-lower-bounds

I have encountered the ratio of the product of the first n odd numbers to the product of the first n even numbers and want to chart its ultimate convergence to zero. If a white noise signal is passed through a cascade of $n$ linear filters, then this ratio is the factor by which the variance of the signal is reduced by the combined action of those $n$ filters. I am, therefore, interested in the rate at which the expression converges such that I can determine the effectiveness of adding more filters.

Of course, doing so requires very large numbers for the numerator and denominator that exceed computing capacity.  Is there a way to approximate the terms of $$\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}$$ for successive n as n becomes large?

Comment: Hint: use Stirling’s formula.

Comment: Framing challenge:  This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  The problem described in the first paragraph is about the partial products of an infinite product of terms in $(0,1)$, which one should have no trouble seeing converge to $0$.  The second paragraph rewrites this in an obscure way, then asks for help with this obscuration.

Comment: It is $2^{-2n}\binom{2n}n.$ Then read about the “central binomial coefficients.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Sorry, @EricTowers , I have re-read my question and the linked XY problem page and I am unable to see how my question is being obscure in the way you suggest.

Comment: You will see in that Wikipedia article that this is $\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews.  That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stirling's approximation gives the following asymptotic for the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient):
$$
{2n \choose n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}
= \frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}
\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

By Stirling's formula, you have
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\Bigl(\cfrac{\not2n}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^{\!2n}}{\not2^{\not2n}\cdot 2\pi n\Bigl(\cfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^{\!2n}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Note that
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_{\,n}  = {{\left( {2n} \right)!} \over {\left( {2^{\,n} n!} \right)^{\,2} }}
 = {{\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{2n - 1} {2n - k} }
 \over {\left( {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} 2 \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {n - k} } \right)^{\,2} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {2n - 2k} \;\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {2n - 2k - 1} }
 \over {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {2n - 2k} \;
 \left( {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} 2 \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {n - k} } \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {n - k - 1/2} } \over {\;\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {n - k} }} =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {1 - {1 \over {2\left( {n - k} \right)}}}  = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {1 - {1 \over {2k}}}  \cr} 
$$

Then pass to $\ln S_n$ and to Riemann sum .

Also, restarting from the above we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & S_{\,n}  = {{\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {n - k - 1/2} } \over {\;\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {n - k} }}
 = {{\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {1/2 + k} } \over {\;\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {1 + k} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {n + 1/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}
 {{\Gamma \left( 1 \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)}}
 = {{\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1/2\,} } } \over {\left( {n + 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,1/2\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  n - 1/2 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \left( \matrix{
   - 1/2 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$
so that
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {S_{\,n} \,x^{\,n} }  = {1 \over {\sqrt {1 - x} }}
$$
and there is plenty of hints for analyzing the asymptotics at different degree of approximation.

Comment: You probably meant $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-\frac{1}{2(n-k)})$

Comment: @Alex : cannot catch the meaning of your comment

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient?wprov=sfti1), we have:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}n=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1-\frac{c_n}{n}\right)
$$
where $\frac19<c_n<\frac18.$

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), equation $(10)$ says
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac13\right)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac14\right)}}
$$
which gives
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac13\right)}}\le\frac{(2n)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}\le\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac14\right)}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Again, without Stirling
$$
\frac{2n!}{(2^n n!)^2} = e^{\log (2n)! - 2 \log 2^n n!} \approx e^{2n \log 2n - 2n +1 - 2n \log 2 - 2n \log n+2n -2} =e^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

*You already received so many good answers that the only thing I could do is to provide a quite good approximation.*

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}=\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi n}} \frac {1-\frac{1}{16 n}+\frac{11}{256 n^2} } {1+\frac{1}{16 n}+\frac{11}{256 n^2} }$$ which shows an absolute relative error smaller than $0.001$% as soon as $n \geq 3$ and smaller than $0.0001$% as soon as $n \geq 5$.

Also, in the same spirit as @robjohn,
$$\frac{(2n)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}\sim \frac1{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n+\frac14+\frac 1{32n}-\frac1 {128n^2}-\frac{5}{2048 n^3}+\frac{23}{8192 n^4}\right)}}$$ could provide tighter bounds. It shows an absolute relative error smaller than $0.001$% as soon as $n \gt 1$ and smaller than $0.0001$% as soon as $n \gt 2$.

Comment: Thank you Claude - how did you come to this approximation?

Comment: @hydrologist. It is almost the same story as the $\frac 1 {30}$ in Ramanujan's approximation of the factorial. Have a look at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629388/on-ramanujans-approximation-n-sim-sqrt-pi-big-frac-ne-bign-sqrt-62/3629529#3629529