# An interesting conjugate-type fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, rational-functions

I was playing around with numbers and I appear to have discovered a very fascinating fraction:

> For all $n>0$, $$\cfrac{\bigg(1-\cfrac 1{3n+2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\cfrac 1{6n+1}\bigg)}{\bigg(1-\cfrac 1{3n+1}\bigg)\bigg(1-\cfrac 1{6n+5}\bigg)}=\cfrac{\bigg(1+\cfrac 1{3n+2}\bigg)\bigg(1+\cfrac 1{6n+1}\bigg)}{\bigg(1+\cfrac 1{3n+1}\bigg)\bigg(1+\cfrac 1{6n+5}\bigg)}$$

How did I derive this?

I was looking at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717594/on-ramanujans-curious-equality-for-sqrt2-1-3-21-7-21-11-2-cd/3624842#3624842) and decided to play around with those mixed fractions (by playing around, I mean multiplying some, dividing others, merely because I was bored). It was greatly to my surprise that I found this (by sheer accident too, due to my interest in conjugates).

Anybody know how to derive this rigorously, and if other such fractions exist?

Thanks.

Comment: "Rigorously" is probably not the word you are looking for. You are asking how to generalize this nontrivially?

Comment: @darijgrinberg ah yes, or find other fractions of similar form. Say, $\cfrac{(x_1+1)(y_1+1)}{(x_2+1)(y_2+1)}=\cfrac{(x_1-1)(y_1-1)}{(x_2-1)(y_2-1)}$

Comment: In other words: $$(x_1x_2-1)(y_1-y_2)+(y_1y_2-1)(x_1-x_2)=0$$

Comment: Incidentally, I realised I could merely substitute $3n\mapsto n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of generalizing that equality. For instance, if you take three natural numbers $a$, $c$, and $f$, and you define$$b=\frac{a-c+af}c,\ d=f-2\frac ca\text{, and }e=\frac{af-a-c}c$$then$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\frac{\left(1-\dfrac1{an+b}\right)\left(1-\dfrac1{cn+d}\right)}{\left(1-\dfrac1{an+e}\right)\left(1-\dfrac1{cn+f}\right)}=\frac{\left(1+\dfrac1{an+b}\right)\left(1+\dfrac1{cn+d}\right)}{\left(1+\dfrac1{an+e}\right)\left(1+\dfrac1{cn+f}\right)}.$$If $a=3$, $c=6$, and $f=5$, this will give you the equality from your question.

Comment: Wow! How did you find that? $(+1)$

Comment: I used Mathematica to write$$\frac{\left(1-\dfrac1{an+b}\right)\left(1-\dfrac1{cn+d}\right)}{\left(1-\dfrac1{an+e}\right)\left(1-\dfrac1{cn+f}\right)}-\frac{\left(1+\dfrac1{an+b}\right)\left(1+\dfrac1{cn+d}\right)}{\left(1+\dfrac1{an+e}\right)\left(1+\dfrac1{cn+f}\right)}$$as a rational function. It's the quocient of two quartic polynomials, whose coefficients are functions of the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$. Then I asked Mathematica to see for which values of those numbers is the numerator the null polynomial. There are lots of solutions (Mathematica found $82$ solutions!).

Comment: Many of them are uninteresting (what I mean by this is that $a=0$ or $c=0$). Finally, among all those solutions, I searched (*without* the help of Mathematica) for a solution of which your equality was a particular case.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. Could you please provide the synthax ? I am curious. Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: Also, it works if $b=\cfrac{a+c+ad}{c}$ and $e=\cfrac{-a+c+ad}{c}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I did it in three steps. First step: to use the `Together` command to convert the expression from my first comment into a rational fraction. After that, `CoefficientList[Numerator[%],n]` to get the list of the coefficients of the numerator. Final step: `Solve[%=={0,0,0,0,0,0},{a,b,c,d,e,f}]`.